# Windows server 2012 R2 slowness issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Each night at approximately 1:30am, server applications slow down to the point were commands, that would normally take a few seconds to complete, take several minutes. The OS of the server is windows 2012 R2 standard and the hardware is HP Proliant DL 380 gen 9. 
                                     We have checked and found that there is no spike in memory or CPU utilization during this time. Also no errors in event viewer. There is no scheduled jobs running during that time..Any ideas folks.....

Comment: Yeah. Ignore CPU and Memory and check disc IO. This smells like nightly backup runs ;) Scheduled jobs - nice try. THis is now how professionals make backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend running Process Monitor as a scheduled task between 1:20 AM and 1:40 AM to capture all events.

As an alternative, you can also schedule PerfMon to run in the same time interval mentioned above.

You can download ProcMon here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

PerfMon Docs - https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2217266&seqNum=2

I also, recommend that you download the AHS log from the iLO 4 web interface, and submit it to HPE Server Support for analysis.